# SQL iterative // recursive cte with conditions (substract from previous rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, iteration, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have this query calculating how many products I have to produce to serve my pending orders and the components I need to produce them.

```
select 
        l.codart as SKU, --final product
        e.codartc as Component, --piece of final product
        e.unicompo, --Components needed for each SKU
        l1.SKU_pending - s.SKU_STOCK as "SKU to produce", 
        s2.C_STOCK as "Component stock", 
        s2.C_STOCK - sum((l1.SKU_pending - s.SKU_STOCK) * e.unicompo)
                            over (partition by e.codartc order by l.codart) as "Component stock after producing"
from linepedi l --table with sales orders
left join escandallo e on e.codartp = l.codart --table with SKU components
inner join (select l1.codart, sum(l1.unidades - l1.uniservida - l1.unianulada) as "SKU_pending" --pending sales. I called it from a subquery so I don't have to repeat the calculation each time I need it
            from linepedi l1
            where (l1.unidades - l1.uniservida - l1.unianulada) > 0
            group by l1.codart) l1 on l1.CODART = l.codart
left join (select s.codart, sum(s.unidades) as "SKU_STOCK"
            from __STOCKALMART s
            group by s.codart) s on s.codart = l.codart
left join (select s.codart, sum(s.unidades) as "C_STOCK"
            from __STOCKALMART s
            group by s.codart) s2 on s2.codart = e.codartc
where       l1.SKU_pending - s.SKU_STOCK > 0
group by    l.codart, e.codartc, e.unicompo, l1.SKU_pending, s.SKU_STOCK, s2.C_STOCK
order by l.codart
```

Query returns next table:

| SKU | Component | unicompo | SKU to produce | Component stock | Component stock after producing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20611 | 286 | 1 | 50 | 2021 | 1971 |
| 20611 | 329 | 1 | 50 | 2759 | 2709 |
| 20611 | ARTZD031 | 1 | 50 | 643 | 593 |
| 220178 | ARTZD027 | 1 | 384 | 477 | 93 |
| 220178 | SICBB005 | 1 | 384 | 845 | 461 |
| 220178 | 265 | 1 | 384 | 894 | 510 |
| 220185 | 265 | 1 | 200 | 894 | 310 |
| 220185 | SICBB005 | 1 | 200 | 845 | 261 |
| 220185 | ARTZD028 | 1 | 200 | 71 | -129 |
| 220192 | ARTZD029 | 1 | 200 | 364 | 164 |
| 220192 | SICBB005 | 1 | 200 | 845 | 61 |
| 220192 | 265 | 1 | 200 | 894 | 110 |

When `Component stock after producing` returns less than 0, I don't want it to substract the `SKU to produce`, but the mininum `Component stock` for that SKU, while "saving" this value for the next time I need the same component. I think I would need to make an iteration with conditionals.

This is what I'd like to accomplish:

| SKU | Component | unicompo | SKU to produce | Component stock | Component stock after producing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20611 | 286 | 1 | 50 | 2021 | 1971 |
| 20611 | 329 | 1 | 50 | 2759 | 2709 |
| 20611 | ARTZD031 | 1 | 50 | 643 | 593 |
| 220178 | ARTZD027 | 1 | 384 | 477 | 93 |
| 220178 | SICBB005 | 1 | 384 | 845 | 461 |
| 220178 | 265 | 1 | 384 | 894 | 510 |
| 220185 | 265 | 1 | 200 | 894 | **439** |
| 220185 | SICBB005 | 1 | 200 | 845 | **390** |
| 220185 | ARTZD028 | 1 | 200 | 71 | **0** |
| 220192 | ARTZD029 | 1 | 200 | 364 | 164 |
| 220192 | SICBB005 | 1 | 200 | 845 | **190** |
| 220192 | 265 | 1 | 200 | 894 | **239** |

I've been reading some articles and I feel like it might be done with a recursive CTE, but I don't really know how since I didn't find any example similar to mine.

How can achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: Side note, `on trim(s.codart) = trim(l.codart)` has a bit of a "code smell" to it. The clause won't be SARGable, so bad for performance, but also why does your data have leading spaces? Seems like some data clean up is needed. *(Trailing spaces are ignored for equality purposes, hence why I "know" the problem is leading spaces.)*

Comment: @Larnu data comes from an ERP that creates those spaces... we tried to clean them up but we couldn't. The trim(s.codart) = trim(l.codart) is not needed, query works fine without trimming the codarts

Comment: *"The trim(s.codart) = trim(l.codart) is not needed,"* Then don't use it; it's only going to make your query perform poorly.

Comment: @Larnu ok, thank you. I thought it didn't affect to its performance.

Comment: *"I thought it didn't affect to its performance"* no, quite the opposite. As I said, it'll make the query non-SARGable, meaning that the indexes on your table can't be used.

Comment: You're asking us to read a _lot_ of code, with a fair number of distracting details - is there a way you could reduce this to a more minimal example highlighting your specific query?

Comment: @SCTomas doesn't adding `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to the OVER() clause of your SUM() function solve your problem ?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I reduced my code a bit. I hope it's more readable now.

Comment: @nfgl I don't know how to apply conditionals with the `over` clause...

Comment: try `over (partition by e.codartc order by l.codart ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

Comment: @nfgl It returns the same results. I'm struggling with the conditions I should apply inside the over clause. I tried to include the `case when` to the `over` clause, but it didn't work (or I didn't know how to make it work) because my conditional should apply to the iteration results, not to the calculation itself